# Cocos2dx Armature bone not show on android device

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, android-animation

I'm using the newest Cocos2d-x 3.3, and make animation by cocos studio 1.6.

The armature animation works well in Win32,

When I run on the android device, the bone animation doesn't appear

but the PhysicsBody(as bounding box) shows at right place.

Does anyone have idea?